# How to specify an input?

Tags: python, input

Does someone know how to do an input like that:

```py
input("Enter a word and a number: ")
```

and in the console we write:

```py
Enter a word and a number: hello 14
```

It reconize it like `[word] [number]`.

Does someone know a "cheat" to do something like that ?

Comment: Input validation is certainly doable. You can either check conditions or use a module like `pyinputplus` which is well-documented and very easy to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
w, n = input("Enter a word and a number:").split(' ')
n = int(n) # to cast the value of the number
```

Answer (score 1):

```
inp = input("Enter a word and a number: ").split()
```

`inp[0]` will be the word and `int(inp[1])` will be the number.

It is important to note that .split() with an empty argument will automatically be interpreted as .split(' ')

Answer (score 1):

`input()` is a super simple function that will just spit out the user input as a string into a variable. If you know the format the input should be in though, you can parse it using regular expressions (if you're familiar with C's `scanf()` you may find this useful: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#simulating-scanf)

In this case, as such:

```py
import re

user_in = input('Enter a word then a number: ')
# Example: bird 15

match = re.search('(\S+) ([-+]?\d+)', user_in)
if match:
    word, number = match.group(1, 2)

print(word)
# Output: bird

print(number)
# Output: 15

print(number + 10)
# Output: 25
```

See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects